# HTACCESS - Applying some simple mod_rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

this is urgent a lot. I need help with some htaccess rules. The clue is when user receives an answer for sth the real url will be www.mydomain.com/results.html/sth but he must can see in his browser only www.mydomain.com/sth only and when i redirect him to home page (www.mydomain.com/index.html) the url has to be www.mydomain.com only.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try my suggestion below?

Answer (score 0):

```
#this is for the www.yourdomain.com/index.html
RewriteRule ^$  index.html  [L]
RewriteRule ^/$  index.html [L]

#this is for the results
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$  results.html?$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ results.html?$1
```

Comment: Thank you. This works for results.html but unfortunately not for homepage index.html. Link to www.mydomain.com/index.html or www.mydomain.com/ takes me to www.mydomain.com/index.html or www.mydomain.com/ but shows content of www.mydomain.com/results.html.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the first 3 lines of code with:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

it should have worked by default though

Comment: Still nothing the same as i described before. Link to www.mydomain.com/ takes me there but content is from www.mydomain.com/results.html unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(results|index)\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /results.html/$1

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
```